# Android App for School Discipline

Tags: android

I am a deputy principal of a primary school. I am in charge of discipline and currently my aim is to develop an Android app for the school's discipline system.

Discipline System that I want to develop must have the following components:
1) A database of +- 760 learners spread over 4 grade groups. Each grade group have 5 classes of +- 38 learners in a specific class = 4 Grade groups x 5 Classes per Grade Group x 38 learners in a class
2) Every learner have five(5) chances/warnings a day but start every day on a clean slate.
3) Parents must receive a message when a learner have received 3 warnings and again at 5 warnings.
4) A report must be compiled from the data entered to track a leaner's behavior.
5) There are 36 warnings divided into 3 groups of 8 warnings.
6) Teachers must be able to use this system on their smart phones.

Can someone please show me how and where do I start? I have limited programming experience but I am a quick and willing learner because I like to take on challenges and make a success of it.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Gerhard

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a deputy principal that have some programming experience and you have will to learn, and you are ambitious, BUT you are asking for help here, saying from where to start ? I don't want to be mean, I am not a genius, not even an experienced programmer, but I think that first thing to do is look up on Google on how to make a Hello World in Android, to do some samples to understand that, read articles, and do some tutorials. You don't need even an average IQ level to do that and to think on doing that first. You need to look over Android, to understand the basic of basics, then know what UI offers, what can you do, and then start searching: how to create a button, a textView, what is a class, an activity, an intent, etc. Or you were hoping that maybe someone made something similar and give you code ? Sorry, maybe I'm harsh but... seriously now.

Hello World Android: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Another site that explains Android : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/index.htm  ( tutorials with PICTURES... YAY !!! )

Great tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/  ( WOW !!! )

Awesome description of Android and explanations: http://www.vogella.com/android.html ( So Pro !! ) [ with some code example: http://www.vogella.com/code/  WOW ! Such Android ]